# Prove: ${n\choose1} +2{n\choose2} +3{n\choose3} +\cdots+n{n\choose n} = n\cdot2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that

$$
{n\choose1} +2{n\choose2} +3{n\choose3} +\cdots+n{n\choose n} = n\cdot2^{n-1}
$$

Now I can prove this using,

$$
{n\choose0}+{n\choose1}x+{n\choose2}x^2 + {n\choose 3}x^3 + \cdots+{n\choose n}x^n = (1+x)^{n}
$$

Differentiating both sides,

$$
{n\choose1} +2{n\choose2}x +3{n\choose3}x^2 +\cdots+n{n\choose n}x^{n-1} = n\cdot(1+x)^{n-1}
$$

Substituting $x=1$, the given identity is proved.

My exercise specifically asks for a combinatorial proof though, [by double counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_%28proof_technique%29).  Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the number of ways to choose a team (with $k\ge 1$ members) and choosing the team's captain. The left hand side counts this based on $k$ and adds the values up (for each $k$, we first choose the team members and then choose one of them as captain). Alternatively, we can first pick one person as the captain ($n$ choices) and then choose the rest of the team (zero or more members out of the remaining $n-1$ people).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have n people and you want to form  a community of sum, possibly all, of those people.  You don’t care how big the committee is, but it does have to have a chairman. One way to choose the committed is to pick the chairman, and then decide which subset of the remaining $n−1$ people will be the other members of the committee. There are n possibilities of choosing the chairman, and then for the other $n-1$ people, you either include the person or not, so there will be $2^{n-1}$ possibilities, so a total of $n2^{n-1}$.

On the other hand, we could begin by deciding how big the committee is going to be, then choosing that many people to be on it, and finally choosing one of those to be the chairman.
For example, for a community of size 1, there will be only a chairman, so only one choice, which is $1 \choose 1$$=1$. Follow this, you can finally get what you are expecting on your left hand side. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}+\cdots+n\binom{n}{n}=$$
$$=n\binom{n-1}{0}+2\frac{n}{2}\binom{n-1}{1}+3\frac{n}{3}\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots+n\binom{n-1}{n-1}=$$
$$=n\binom{n-1}{0}+n\binom{n-1}{1}+n\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots+n\binom{n-1}{n-1}=$$
$$=n\left(\binom{n-1}{0}+\binom{n-1}{1}+\binom{n-1}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n-1}{n-1}\right)=n2^{n-1}$$

Comment: I really do not know why a downvote when the OP asks precisely this answer?

Comment: The OP has asked for a proof by double-counting; s/he already has an algebraic proof.